# Minimize Console at app startup C#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a Console Application app, I would like to minimize (not hide permanently) the Console when i run the app, is it possible?
also, I am using a timer to run the task every 10 minutes, is it possible to minimize the console every time the app runs?
thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate? [.Net Console Application in System tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751944/net-console-application-in-system-tray)

Comment: I dont want to put it the the system tray. I just want it minimized

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following code should do the trick. Uses Win32 methods to minimize the console window. I am using Console.ReadLine() to prevent the window closing immediately.

```
internal class Program
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow([In] IntPtr hWnd, [In] int nCmdShow);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

        ShowWindow(handle, 6);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: used different method, but your answer helped me

Comment: It would be nice to feedback and say what method you did use

Comment: Gotta say this out loud - I mistakenly downvoted this answer for absolute no reason (didnt realize until saw colored down arrow today). I apologize for this, as I can't fix that now (21 hours pass, my vote is locked), but it should have been an upvote, since this answer works just like it should!!!

Comment: To clarify, the `6` corresponds to `SW_MINIMIZE` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001655